# Turning a unique number derived from a string into a good hashcode

Tags: java, string, hashcode

I have an application that needs to compare a lot of small strings very quickly.  Fortunately, I could guarantee the following about all of the strings:

- Only the first 6 characters in each string are considered significant; differences in any remaining characters are to be ignored
- The comparisons are to be case insensitive
- Only (English) alphabetic characters, "-" and "'" are allowed in the strings.

It occurred to me that it was possible therefore to take each string and convert it into an `int` that could be directly compared with other `int`s produced from other strings, thus converting a potentially-costly string comparison into a single-cycle integer comparison.

I also, however, need to use these strings as keys in hashtables (specifically, Java's `HashMap` and `HashSet` classes), and was wondering whether the numbers I produce can be used as good hash codes, or easily converted into them, or if I should also generate a hashcode for my objects using a more traditional string hashing algorithm.  I could run a performance test myself, but it occurs to me that this exact question is something that somebody is very likely to have evaluated before; I'm just struggling to find any good information about it.

My unique number generation code is as below:

```
private int stringMatcherCode (String word)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() && i < 6; i ++)
    {
        char ch = word.charAt (i);
        if (ch == '-') ch = (char)28;  // does not contain the same last 5 bits as any letter
        if (ch == '\'') ch = (char)29; // nor this
        total = (total << 5) | (ch & 0x1F);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly not a good hash function, as is, for your HashMap because the backing array would have 2^30 bins. You are most likely better off with the standard implementations unless there is a real need for and understanding of improvement.

Comment: I need to calculate the number I am calculating, as the standard hashcode implementation is not guaranteed to be unique for any arbitrary input strings.  My application is performance critical, so I wish to avoid the unnecessary duplication of effort in also calculating the hashcode via the standard algorithm if this is possible.  Can you elaborate on why this would require more than the standard number of bins in the hashmap?  This comment makes little sense to me.

Comment: @Jules Will you call the `stringMatcherCode` more than on time for the same `String`? I'm asking that because the second call to `String.hashcode` is atomic.

Comment: No.  The result of calling it will be stored instead of storing the String.

Comment: @Jules the reason a hash table has constant time lookup (amortized, due to dealing with collisions) is that it computes the hash function of each key and finds the value stored at that index. That's fundamentally what a hash table is. ... It would be reasonable to choose a prime number `p` several times larger than the number of values you expected to store, and use that as the hash table size, computing your function mod `p`. I can appreciate wanting to save some work recomputing hash values, but we aren't talking about a difference in running time complexity, are we?

Comment: No, but we are talking about an order-of-magnitude or more difference in running speed of the hashtable-related operations, which allowed me to shave 6 seconds off an 8 second processing time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The key insight that I didn't have when I asked the question is that Java's HashMap implementation uses power-of-two sized tables (I had assumed it worked the way I learned years ago, where you kept the size of the table to a prime number).  Given my implementation, only the earlier characters will therefore be significant in choosing the bucket any given string maps to.  A prime number is therefore a better choice of multipler -- 31 is not good for me, however, as I can guarantee uniqueness as easily when using it as I can with 32.  33 does work, however, as 33^6 is still < 2^32, so no overflow occurs, so this implementation both guarantees uniqueness *and* works as a good hash code:

```
private int stringMatcherCode (String word)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() && i < 6; i ++)
    {
        char ch = word.charAt (i);
        if (ch == '-') ch = (char)28;  // does not contain the same last 5 bits as any letter
        if (ch == '\'') ch = (char)29; // nor this
        total = (total * 33) + (ch & 0x1F);
    }
    return total;
}
```